# Limiting moments and asymptotic moments of a statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics

1. From Casella's Statistical Inference:

   > Definition 10.1.7 For an estimator $T_n$, if $\lim_{n\to \infty} k_n Var T_n = \tau^2 < \infty$, where $\{k_n\}$ is a sequence of
   >   constants, then $\tau^2$ is called **the limiting variance** or
   >   **limit of the variances** of $T_n$.
   >
   > Definition 10.1.9 For an estimator $T_n$, suppose that $k_n(T_n - \tau(\theta)) \to n(0, \sigma^2)$ in distribution. The parameter
   >   $\sigma^2$ is called **the asymptotic variance** or **variance of
   >   the limit distribution** of $T_n$.

   - I was wondering if both definitions depend on the choice of the
     sequence $k_n$, because I suspect for some choice of the sequence
     $k_n$, the convergence may fail, while for some other choice of the
     sequence $k_n$, the convergence may succeed. Then are the two
     definitions not well defined, because aren't they supposed to be not
     dependent on the choice of the sequence $k_n$?

     For example, in [Lyapunov CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT), $\frac{1}{s_n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu_i) \ \xrightarrow{d}\ \mathcal{N}(0,\;1)$ where $ s_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 $. According to the above definition of asymptotic variance, $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, $\tau(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i$ (should \tau(\theta) be independent of sample size $n$?), and the asymptotic variance of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is $1$  (this is hard to believe, because the variance $\sigma_i^2$ of $X_i$ can be any as long as it is finite)?
   - Can the limiting distribution in the definition of the asymptotic
     variance to be other  than a Normal distribution?
   - When will the limiting variance and the asymptotic variance be the
     same?
2. Similarly but more generally,

   - how can we define limiting moments and
     asymptotic moments?
   - Is the limiting distribution in the definition of an asymptotic
     moment required to be a Normal distribution?
   - When will the limiting moment and the asymptotic moment coincide?

   For example, those two concepts for means: limiting mean and
   asymptotic mean?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252669 for a concrete example of a difference between limiting and asymptotic moments.

Answer (score 7):

**Asymptotic Moments**
Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables with cumulative distribution function $F_n(x)$. If this sequence converges in distribution to a random variable $X$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_n(x) = F(x)$ for every point of continuity of $F(x)$, then the asymptotic moments of $\{X_n\}$ are the moments of the limiting distribution $F(x)$.

**Limiting moments**
Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables with cumulative distribution function $F_n(x)$. For every moment $M_{n,r}$ of $F_n(x)$ that exists, the limiting moment is defined as $M_r \equiv \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}M_{n,r}$.

**When the two coincide?**
If

1. $M_r \equiv \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}M_n(r)$ is finite (i.e. if the limiting moment is a real number)
2. There exists $\delta > 0 : E\left(|X_n|^{r+\delta}\right) < K < \infty\;\; \forall n$

then, if $X_n \rightarrow_d X$, the limiting moment $M_r$ will be the asymptotic moment also.

**Note:** $K$ is any finite positive constant.