# Bias-variance trade-off for a specific fitted model vs. a class of models: terminology

Tags: terminology, bias-variance-tradeoff

Consider a data generating process
$$Y=f(X)+\varepsilon$$
where $\varepsilon$ is independent of $x$ with $\mathbb E(\varepsilon)=0$ and $\text{Var}(\varepsilon)=\sigma^2_\varepsilon$. According to Hastie et al. ["The Elements of Statistical Learning"](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) (2nd edition, 2009) Section 7.3 p. 223, we can derive an expression for the expected prediction error of a regression fit $\hat g(X)$ at an input point $X=x_0$, using squared-error loss:

\begin{align}
\text{Err}(x_0)
&=\mathbb E[(Y-\hat g(x_0))^2|X=x_0]\\
&=(\mathbb E[\hat g(x_0)−f(x_0)])^2+\mathbb E[(\hat g(x_0)−\mathbb E[\hat g(x_0)])^2]+\sigma^2_\varepsilon\\
&=\text{Bias}^2\ \ \ \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\;+\text{Variance } \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad+ \text{ Irreducible Error}
\end{align}

(where I use the notation $\text{Bias}^2$ instead of $\text{Bias}$ and $\hat g$ instead of $\hat f$).

Recently, I caught myself using the same term, *bias*, in two situations:

1. Just as above, $\text{Bias}=\mathbb E[\hat g(x_0)−f(x_0)]$ for a specific <del>fitted model</del>
   $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\hat g}$ sample size $n$ and referring to a specific value $x_0$ of the regressors.
2. Referring to the ability of a class of models $g$ to approximate $f$ across different values of $x_0$ given infinite data. In this sense, $g(x)=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\beta_2 x^2$ is an "unbiased" class of models for $f(x)=0.5+2x$, because $0.5+2x$ is a special case of $\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\beta_2 x^2$, and given infinite data we can learn the values of $(\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2)$ to be $(0.5,2,0)$.

Is there a better term than *bias* to refer to the second case? Perhaps *asymptotic bias*?

Comment: How do I cross out a symbol in MathJax? `\sout` is not working.

Comment: Richard, please check if that works.

Comment: @User1865345, that works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the term "bias" tends to be used as a blanket term to indicate generally deviation from the true value. E.g. one finds expressions like *"...then the estimator will be inconsistent and the estimates will be biased"*: the use of the word "bias" here does not refer to its formal sense and definition.

The specific case the OP describes is a case of "nested models": if we are lucky enough to specify a model that *nests* the true Data Generating Mechanism, then... it becomes a matter of whether the estimator we are using is consistent asymptotically even in the presence of redundant regressors (like the $x^2$ in the OP's example).

As regards terminology around "asymptotic bias", I guess the following two posts could be useful:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/245074/28746

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/239919/28746

...responding to the OP's comment, as regards which, after all, could be a proper terminology for case 2. in his post, I would suggest **"asymptotically equivalent"**,
-- if by using $g(x)$ we will end up with the correct coefficient vector.

So "model $g(x)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $f(x)$ because as data goes to infinity $g(x)$ converges to $f(x)$."

Comment: Good point about the need for a consistent estimator. (I thought about it at some point but did not include in the post.) Given your two links, *asymptotic bias* seems to be taken. But just *bias* is "even more taken"...

Comment: Hmm. If $f(x)$ is nested in $g(x)$, the relationship is asymmetric. So if we use *asymptotically equivalent*, we would have both *g(x) is asymptotically equivalent to $f(x)$* and *f(x) is **not** asymptotically equivalent to $f(x)$* at once. I would be more comfortable using the term [asymptotically] *equivalent* for a symmetric relationship than an asymmetric one.

Comment: @RichardHardy It's up to you, but I personally find this unjustified. The two functions have implicitly distinct/asymmetric roles, since the one represents the data generating mechanism, and the other a model of it. If you want to treat both as models of some third function/DGP, then whether they are asymptotically equivalent or not depends on what is this 3rd generating mechanism. So on my part I see no problem saying <<a model is asymptotically equivalent to the true data generating mechanism>>.

Comment: That is a helpful point, thank you.